# How to access a template struct const variable in CPP

Tags: c++, templates

I am working with a code in which I am passing a constant variable to a templated struct like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

template<typename T>

struct Data {
    T age;
};

void show();

int main()
{

      Data<const int> person{
        18
      };

      cout << person.age;

     show();

}


void show(){




}
```

In the code, I want to read the const variable ' T age ' (T age value is 18 assigned by the main function),inside the function' show() ' without passing the struct variable as an argument.

Here is what I tried

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

template<typename T>

struct Data {
    T age;
};

void show();

int main()
{

      Data<const int> person{
          18
      };

      cout << person.age;

      show();

}


void show(){

      Data<const int> person;

      cout << person.age;


}
```

The error message

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘void show()’:
source_file.cpp:32:18: error: use of deleted function ‘Data<const int>::Data()’
  Data<const int> person;
              ^~~~~~
source_file.cpp:10:12: note: ‘Data<const int>::Data()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     struct Data {
            ^~~~
source_file.cpp:10:12: error: uninitialized const member in ‘struct Data<const int>’
source_file.cpp:11:8: note: ‘const int Data<const int>::age’ should be initialized
      T age;
        ^~~
```

So how can I read the value of 'T age' inside the function 'show()' without passing the struct variable as an argument from ' int main()' ?

Correction with code and proper explanation is highly desired.

Comment: You can declare `person` as global variable... but I strongly discourage the use of global variables. Or maybe you can define `show()`, inside `main()`, as a lambda function, capturing `person`; something as `auto show = [&]{ std::cout << person.age; };`

Comment: My advice is pass a person to show using a reference. Or make show to be a member of Data

Comment: @Max66 I am really sorry bro, in my code , I must not use lambda , I only want to read the variable from the user defined function show().

Comment: @drescherjm a code example please

Comment: Right after `T age;` and before the next `};` put `void show() { cout << age; }`

Comment: Then in main `person.show();`

Comment: @drescherjm but, will I be able to call the function from outside the main() from any other function instead of the main? I guess not?

Comment: You will not be able to do that without using parameters or a global variable (which you should avoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code simply does not work. The `person` variable is not populated to the `show()`'s body, so inside that function you just create a default struct where you do not specify a value. In the end, it crashes.

What you can do is:

1. Pass a structure to the function and get its inner variable.
2. Create a static structure in the global space and read it inside your function.
3. Use lambdas.

Comment: One key point is naming a variable the same in some other scope makes no connection between variables. They don't share values or anything.